# CSS class naming with className not displaying by the DOM but attribute naming class display fine when I import it from my NPM package

Tags: css, reactjs, import, rename, npm-package

After I publish my first package with create-react-library (that is a modal component), I install it into another project.
The modal works fine but the CSS style who generate by className not displaying.

```
  .content{
    width: 500px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
  }
```

On the other side, style generate by HTML tags is apply by the DOM.

```
  h1 {
    margin:0;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
```

No errors but there is one thing that interpellate me :

I import the CSS from the 'test2-react-simple-modal/dist/index.css' path.
In the node_module and in my dist folder, my class names are changed to some weird naming like

```
 ._index__content__3NYI6{
    width: 500px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
  }
```

I think there is something here.

Can you tell me more about ? Why CSS classnames changed this way and how to export/import them well ?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using a Wix or Gui website builder? or could be just the settings you have on your package..

Comment: @Riskbreaker  I know that my original code changes when I distribute it before publishing it, I think it is during this process that the names of my classes change in my css files and therefore the DOM does not associate them with those declared from js/jsx file (className={})